# Como eu seleciono 3 linhas depois do Id = 2?

Tags: mysql, sql-select

Imaginemos que temos a seguinte tabela (produtos):

| Id | Descrição |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | P1 |
| 2 | P2 |
| 3 | P3 |
| 4 | P4 |
| 5 | P5 |
| 6 | P6 |

Eu quero selecionar (select), a tabela produtos, apartir de onde id = 3, até onde id=5

Isso quer dizer que ele deve retornar todas as linhas apartir da id = 3 até I'd = 5.

Output:

| Id | Descrição |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | P3 |
| 4 | P4 |
| 5 | P5 |

Agradeço desde já toda ajuda. ❤️

Comment: `where id>=3 and id <=5` ou `where id between 3 and 5`

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usar a função `LIMIT`, a qual você escolhe a quantidade desejada de itens a serem retornados:

```
SELECT * FROM Product
WHERE Id >= 3
ORDER BY Id LIMIT 3
```

Você poder ver funcionando em: [Função LIMIT MySql](https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3yyzgbtx3)

---

#### Função LIMIT

A função LIMIT é usada para especificar o número de registros a serem retornados. É útil em tabelas grandes com milhares de registros. Retornar um grande número de registros pode afetar o desempenho.

Comment: Se a pessoa que deu voto negativo pudesse informar o motivo para que eu possa melhorar essa resposta e as próximas, seria muito importante.